# Rendering only included when devtools is open?

Tags: javascript, razor

I am trying to make a "click here to print page"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PrintElem ()
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.head.innerHTML)
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(document.body.children[1].innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
}
</script>

<a onClick="printElem()" href="#"> print a div! </a>
```

All the stylings is included in Head, but for some reason are these skipped, when i click the `print a div!` link, but inlcuded when i click it with DevTools open?

Why?

Comment: Your code has at least two capitalization errors, and I would expect `document.children[1]` to be `undefined`, which causes the code to completely fail. When I fix the problems and try this in Codepen, it works just fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvMdNZ

Answer (score 1):

You were so close here. Your function `PrintElem()` should not be capitalized, as you're calling it with proper camel-case `printElem()`

Works fine when correcting that capitalization issue. No other changes are necessary.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printElem ()
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.head.innerHTML)
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(document.body.children[1].innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
}
</script>

<a onClick="printElem()" href="#"> print a div! </a>
```